# List appending and deleting

Tags: python, beginner

Here I have a list which is months = ["Jan", "May", "Jul", "Aug", "Oct", "Dec"]

I want to do the following with this list

- append months that are missing  --->
  months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
- Delete months at index [2,5,9] from the list --->
  months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Nov', 'Dec']

Can you please help me improve the code with list appending and deleting?.

**I did the following**

```
months = ["Jan", "May", "Jul", "Aug", "Oct", "Dec"]

# Appending "Feb", "Mar","Apr", "Jun" and "Sep" into months
months[1:1]= ["Feb", "Mar","Apr"]
months[5:5]= ["Jun"]
months[8:8]= ["Sep"]
months[10:10]= ["Nov"]
print("All months: ", months) 

# Deleting index 2, 5, 9
del_index = [2, 5, 9]
months = [i for i in months if months.index(i) not in del_index]
print("Del Months:" , months)
```

**Outputs**

```
All months:  ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
Del Months: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

Comment: Is `months` list going to always contain the same months / missing months? that's how it looks from you code but I just want to make sure

Comment: no, first --> months = ["Jan", "May", "Jul", "Aug", "Oct", "Dec"], after appending -->  months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'] then after deleting --> months =  ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Nov', 'Dec']

Comment: You didn't gen my question: is the first list (the one with the missing months) always going to be the same and ordered (by months)?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be in that order.

Comment: Why not just do `months = <the complete list of all 12 months>`?

Comment: You are not appending `"Feb", "Mar","Apr", "Jun" and "Sep"`, you are inserting them at the correct positions, which you had to calculate by hand.  There isn't much of a program here -- are you certain you've followed the problems instructions correctly?

Answer (score 1):

So, if the resulting `months` list always needs to have all 12 months, regardless of what it had before your operation, then there is no need to insert or append:

```py
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
print("All months: ", months)
```

For "deleting" you can build a subset of your list with:

```py
months = [month for i, month in enumerate(months) if i not in del_index]
```

Comment: For an easier way of defining a list of all months one can do: `import calendar; all_months=list(calendar.month_abbr)`